# How do I vertically center an <a> element within a flex div?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, flexbox, centering

Why can I center a button with flex but not a link?

```css
#quote-btn-div {
  display: flex;
}
#quote-btn,
#twitter-link {
  background-color: #999;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#twitter-link {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="quote-box">
  <div id="quote-btn-div">
    <button id="quote-btn">New Quote</button>
    <a id="twitter-link">Twitter link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm still learning.

Comment: Where do you want the link to go? And do you mean horizontally centered? The easiest way is probably to move the twitter link somewhere else, especially since the parent div is `#quote-btn-div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line-height` is often used to vertically center a single line of text. Since you have set a height on your button, set `line-height` to that value.

`#twitter-link { line-height: 100px; }`

```css
#quote-btn-div {
  display: flex;
}
#quote-btn,
#twitter-link {
  background-color: #999;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#twitter-link {
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="quote-box">
  <div id="quote-btn-div">
    <button id="quote-btn">New Quote</button>
    <a id="twitter-link">Twitter link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#twitter-link {
  line-height: 100px;
}
```